# wget for FTP end in "connection refused"

Tags: debian, ftp, wget

I want to copy a FTP directory to my server (Debian) using wget command. I tried :

```
wget -m --user=user --password=passftp://ftp.domain.com
```

I've got this error :

```
connection... failed : Connection refused
```

I tried to export ftp_proxy but I don't know what I have to fill here ? The IP of my server ? Something else ?

Also, I tried ncftpget but I've got :

```
Unknown host
```

Comment: "I tried ncftpget" What `ncftpget` command did you actually try?

Answer (score 1):

#### I want to copy a FTP directory to my server (Debian) using wget

```
wget -m --user=user --password=passftp://ftp.domain.com
```

There are several errors in the above command.

1. You are missing a <kbd>space</kbd> between `pass` and `ftp://ftp.domain.com`
2. You need to use different options (`--ftp-user` and `--ftp-password`) when accessing an FTP Server.

Try the following command:

```
get -m --ftp-user=user --ftp-password=pass ftp://ftp.domain.com
```

Alternative (URL format):

```
get -m ftp://user:pass@ipaddress
```

where `ipaddress` is the IP address of `ftp.domain.com`

---

#### 2.1 URL Format

> URL is an acronym for Uniform Resource Locator. A uniform resource
>   locator is a compact string representation for a resource available
>   via the Internet. Wget recognizes the URL syntax as per RFC1738. This
>   is the most widely used form (square brackets denote optional parts):
>
> ```
> http://host[:port]/directory/file
> ftp://host[:port]/directory/file
> ```
>
> You can also encode your username and password within a URL:
>
> ```
> ftp://user:password@host/path
> http://user:password@host/path
> ```
>
> Either user or password, or both, may be left out. If you leave out
>   either the HTTP username or password, no authentication will be sent.
>   If you leave out the FTP username, ‘anonymous’ will be used. If you
>   leave out the FTP password, your email address will be supplied as a
>   default password.

Source [GNU Wget 1.17.1 Manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html#URL-Format)

---

#### 2.9 FTP Options

> ```
> --ftp-user=user
> --ftp-password=password
> ```
>
> Specify the username `user` and password `password` on an FTP server.
>
> Without this, or the corresponding startup option, the password
>   defaults to `-wget@`, normally used for anonymous FTP.
>
> Another way to specify username and password is in the URL itself (see
>   URL Format). Either method reveals your password to anyone who bothers
>   to run ps. To prevent the passwords from being seen, store them in
>   `.wgetrc` or `.netrc`, and make sure to protect those files from other
>   users with chmod. If the passwords are really important, do not leave
>   them lying in those files either—edit the files and delete them after
>   `Wget` has started the download.

Source [GNU Wget 1.17.1 Manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html#FTP-Options)